# Loading decimal numbers from django form (formset) into number input

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms, validation

I am creating a simple django app where you can create recipes with ingredients. On my `RecipeCreate` view I have a simple formset with a `select` input (where you select a product) and a `input type="number"` with the product count. So my form and model are quite simple:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    count = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

class IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ('product', 'count')
```

Now when i want to display my recipe on my `RecipeEdit` view everything loads fine except for the `count` input. I get the following jQuery validation error:

```
The specified value "12,00" is not a valid number. The value 
must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

Because I'm writing a Polish website I would like to have our national standard decimal separator, which is a `,` not a `.` (but the dot should also be a separator).

One of the solutions would be to use an `input type="text"` but it would mean I have to validate my number manually, which is troublesome. 
Is there any way to pass my number `12,00` so that it is accepted by the input field. Probably changing/overwriting the standard jQuery validation? But I will accept any good suggested solution.

Another curious fact is that when I write manually `12,00` or `12.00` and submit my form, my form is valid and my `Ingredient` count field has a value od 12 which is what I desire. It's another pro for the `input type="number"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've done something like this. First of all I am using an input type="text". Then using [jQuery.numeric()](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) I convert my input so that it only accepts numbers, and a `,` as decimal separator.

```
$("#field_id").numeric({ decimal : "," });
```

Now every time i submit my form I have some code that converts my `,` into `.` so that it fits the backend logic:

```
$('#recipe-form').on('submit', function(){
    $('.convert-separator').each(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(',','.'));
    });
    this.submit();
});
```

But I think it's not the best solution. I think there must be a possibility to use the `input type="number"` field with a `,` separator.

Answer (score 1):

You could set your locale [decimal separator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#decimal-separator)

UPDATE:

Didnt saw it is jquery related,

you could create new validator class for comma numbers for instance

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("commanumber", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(\d+|\d+,\d{1,2})$/.test(value);
}, "Please specify the correct number format");
```

or even extend regex to support . also

Comment: I was using `USE_L10N` so because of that my decimal separator is `,`, like mentioned in my question. If I set my decimal separator to `.` it's true that I wouldn't have the warning message. But even after `document.ready` I still couldn't change my decimal separator to `,`, because `type="number"` wouldn't allow it.

Comment: what is the language tag (LANGUAGE_CODE) you are using

Comment: LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl'

Comment: I really like this option with the custom validator. Could you tell me how to use it? Is it possible to use it on a `input type="number"` field, so that it overrides standard validtion?

Comment: The part with extending the regex is also a way I was thinking about, but despite I've been changing my regex in my `jquery.min.js` file it wasn't seen in my browser. I was using `CTRL+F5`, but I don't know why my browser saw always the old file, with the old regex. When changing `jquery.min.js` PyCharm told me: `Generated source files should not be edited. The changes will be lost when sources are regenerated` so I gave up on this. Maybe you know how to avoid this issue?

Comment: I've been also changing my jquery.js file, and added it instead of the min file, but the effect was the same

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the count value in your jQuery code:

```
dotCount = count.toString().replace(',', '.');
```

This replaces the comma with a dot

Comment: Sure, but it would still mean i get a warning in my console first and then I have a number input with a `.` as a separator. I would like to have a `,` as my standard initial separator, but it should also accept a `.`

Answer (score 0):

I found [nice article](https://ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization) which one can describe your problem. Author recommended to use lang attribute e.g `<html lang="en-150">` or `<input type="number" lang="en-150">`.

There is also a [note](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#input-author-notes) on [www.w3.org](https://www.w3.org/)

> 4.10.5.2 Implemention notes regarding localization of form controls
>
> This section is non-normative.
>
> The formats shown to the user in date, time, and number controls is
>   independent of the format used for form submission.
>
> Browsers are encouraged to use user interfaces that present dates,
>   times, and numbers according to the conventions of either the locale
>   implied by the input element's language or the user's preferred
>   locale. Using the page's locale will ensure consistency with
>   page-provided data.
>
> > For example, it would be confusing to users if an American English
> >     page claimed that a Cirque De Soleil show was going to be showing on
> >     02/03, but their browser, configured to use the British English
> >     locale, only showed the date 03/02 in the ticket purchase date picker.
> >     Using the page's locale would at least ensure that the date was
> >     presented in the same format everywhere. (There's still a risk that
> >     the user would end up arriving a month late, of course, but there's
> >     only so much that can be done about such cultural differences...)

Comment: Looks quite ok, but the problem is in the jQuery validation. Does not really work.